# Get the sha1-hashed value from XML signature value

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, xml-signature, rsa-sha256

I need someone to help me understand XML digital signature method **rsa-sha1**. I suppose the signature value = RSA-encrypt(sha1(signedInfo), privatekey).

Note Base64.encode(sha1(signedInfo)) contains 28 characters. So I think Base64.encode(RSA-decrypt(signaturevalue), publickey) should return 28 characters as well. However, I actually got a 48-character string.

```
Base64 base64 = new Base64();
byte[] encrypted = base64.decode(signatureValue);
try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getX509Cert().getPublicKey());
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

        System.out.println(base64.encodeToString(cipherText));
        //print out MCEwCQYFKw4DAhoFAAQU0G+7jFPydS/sWGO1QPjB0v3XTz4=
        //which contains 48 characters. 
 }
 catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Signature method as indicated in XML file

```
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
```

Comment: Why not use the [Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html) class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSA signing is not actually the same as encrypting with the private key, but JCE promotes this mistake by allowing 'backwards' operations in `Cipher` for RSA (only) which actually do PKCS1-v1_5 signature and recovery instead of encryption and decryption as they were designed to.

For the original standardized RSA signature scheme in PKCS1 through v1.5, now retronymed RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5, the value that is padded (with 'type' 01 multiple FFs and one 00) and modexp'ed with the private key is **not just the hash but an ASN.1 structure containing the hash**. See the encoding operation EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 in [section 9.2 of rfc8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2) or rfc3447 or 9.2.1 in rfc2437, especially step 2 and (for the newer two versions) 'Notes' item 1.

Dupe [Using SHA1 and RSA with java.security.Signature vs. MessageDigest and Cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521101/using-sha1-and-rsa-with-java-security-signature-vs-messagedigest-and-cipher)
and [Separate digest & signing using java security provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490188/separate-digest-signing-using-java-security-provider)

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085! Using the information you provided I was able to find the answer.